# Regular Expression quantifiers which skip non-matching expressions without resetting the count

Tags: matlab, regex-lookarounds

How would I build a regexp that removes the beginning of the input string up to the first two words that are not Stack-Overflowers?

```
defaultCase = '1.2.3.4 Hello\ - my name is Bob'
nonDefault1 = '1.2.3.4 Hello Stack-Overflowers - my name is Bob, I have a question'
nonDefault2 = '1.2.3.4 Stack-Overflowers - Hello - my name is Bob and I like regexps'
```

All these cases would ideally output the rest of the string starting with 'my name is Bob'.

The default case is fairly easy to handle

```
`%Returns 'my name is Bob'`
`matchedString = regexpi(defaultCase,'(?<=^(\S*\w\S*\s[\s\W]*){2})\w.*','match','once')`
```

The two non-default cases require some application of negative look arounds.

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to look like for each of your three cases?

Comment: Whoops sorry - ended up removing an important part in my search for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by gradually building up a regular expression piece by piece.

```
%Demonstration Cases
defaultCase = '1.2.3.4 Hello\ - my name is Bob'
nonDefault1 = '1.2.3.4 Hello Stack-Overflowers - my name is Bob, I have a question'
nonDefault2 = '1.2.3.4 Stack-Overflowers - Hello - my name is Bob and I like regexps';

%Word to skip during counting
skipBasic = 'Stack-Overflowers';

%Set up the regular expression
word = '(\S*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\S*)';
space = '(\s[\W\s_]*)';
skipWord = ['(\S*' skipBasic '\S*)'];
skipWordSpace = ['(',skipWord space '?)'];
wordSpace = ['(',word space '?)'];
nonSkipWord = ['(\<(?!' skipWord ')' word '\>)'];
pairedWord = ['(' skipWordSpace '*' nonSkipWord ')'];
firstTwoPairedWords = ['^(' pairedWord space '){2}'];
unwantedFirstPart = ['(' firstTwoPairedWords,skipWordSpace,'*)'];
wantedPart = ['(?<=' unwantedFirstPart ')' nonSkipWord space wordSpace '*'];

%Create the parser 
endString = @(inputString) regexpi(inputString,wantedPart,'match','once');

%Apply the parser to the examples
disp(endString(defaultCase))
disp(endString(nonDefault1))
disp(endString(nonDefault2))
```

Breaking the regular expression into into manageable bits makes it much more understandable. Here's - the end result which I could never have achieved freehand.

`'(?<=(^((((\S*Stack-Overflowers\S*)(\s[\W\s_]*)?)*(\<(?!(\S*Stack-Overflowers\S*))(\S*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\S*)\>))(\s[\W\s_]*)){2}((\S*Stack-Overflowers\S*)(\s[\W\s_]*)?)*))(\<(?!(\S*Stack-Overflowers\S*))(\S*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\S*)\>)(\s[\W\s_]*)((\S*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\S*)(\s[\W\s_]*)?)*'`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is the kind of problem that will drive you to madness if you try to solve it using only regular expressions. They are a very powerful instrument, but sometimes they cannot be the only one... and, fortunately, Matlab offers a wide variety of tools to play with. This is my baby-steps suggestion:

```
clear all;

defaultCase = '1.2.3.4 Hello\ - my name is Bob';
nonDefault1 = '1.2.3.4 Hello Stack-Overflowers - my name is Bob';
nonDefault2 = '1.2.3.4 Stack-Overflowers - Hello - my name is Bob';

a = GetText(defaultCase);
b = GetText(nonDefault1,'Stack-Overflowers');
c = GetText(nonDefault2,'Stack-Overflowers');

function res = GetText(input,exc)
    if (nargin < 2)
        exc = {''};
    end

    if (ischar(exc))
        exc = {exc};
    end

    % split the string into chunks
    res = strsplit(input,' ');

    % detect the chunks that contain only special characters
    rem_reg = cellfun(@(x)isempty(regexp(x,'^\W+$','once')),res,'UniformOutput',true);

    % detect the words that should be excluded
    rem_exc = ~strcmp(res,exc);

    % filter the original array of chunks based on the above criterions
    res = res(rem_reg & rem_exc);

    % return the final result
    res = strjoin(res(3:end),' ');
end
```

Comment: If I allow multiple lines, it ends up being pretty simple - simply regexprep the undesired words out of the input string i.e. `modifiedInput = regexprep(inputString,['\S*',exc,'\S*'],'')`, and then run the original regexp `matchedString = regexpi(modifiedInput ,'(?<=^(\S*\w\S*\s[\s\W]*){2})\w.*','match','once')`. I'm attempting to use an existing framework however that only allows a single regular expression to be used. .